# Average of angles between 0 and 179 degrees?

Tags: geometry

I have a list of n angles that range between 0 and 179 degrees, as for my application I'm only interested in direction.

Now I'd like to "merge" these angles into a type of "consensus direction". This ought to be the average of these directions as far as I can tell, but since the angles are between 0 and 179 degrees I can't average the sine and cosines.

Some examples of averages I'm looking for:

- The angles [10, 20, 30] should average to 20
- The angles [0, 170, 160] should average to 170
- The angles [170, 20, 25] should average to 11.666...

Here is an illustration of the problem:

[image: An illustration of the problem]

Angles a, b and c are arbitrary angles between 0 and 179 degrees. Hence they appear as lines rather than vectors. What I'm looking for is a "consensus" angle, like the red one in the image, which acts as an average of the input angles.

Comment: Why is 170 the average of 0,170,160?

Comment: because the 180 degree angle has wrapped around to 0. Let me draw an illustration and add it to the post.

Comment: But from vertical or Horizontal axis

Comment: I suppose you want something like: Given unit vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, you want another unit vector $v$ for which $\sum |v\cdot v_i|$ is maximized?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I do believe this case acts as a regular vector averaging problem indeed, but the problem I ran into is that angles wrap around at 180 instead of 360. So in a way vectors have two directions; one pointing in (angle) and one pointing in (angle + 180).

The directions represent tangents to edges of a shape, so whether they point in one direction or the opposite is not relevant here, and that is exactly the problem.

Comment: @Bartvbl I think the arrow on the red line in your diagram is misleading. The whole point of your question is that the other lines are directionless.

Comment: @almagest Good point. I updated the image.

Comment: Let the given angles be $a_1,\dots,a_n$. You may have to do something like minimise $\sum\min((x-a_i)^2,(180-x-a_i)^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider splitting the directions into three quadrants:
[image: Quadrants]]

Each direction that is not in the right quadrant, adds one angle to both top and bottom quadrants. (Consider any line with angle 0° to 180° with the vertical, and you'll see this is true.)

Since any line that is in the right quadrant is also in the left quadrant, but we're only interested in directions to the right, we can safely ignore the leftmost (white) quadrant.

Calculate the average angle using those in the top and right quadrants, and another average using those in the right and bottom quadrants. Of these two averages, select the average that is closer to 90°, directly right.

In pseudocode:

```
sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0
sum3 = 0
num13 = 0
num2  = 0

for each angle a:

    if a < 45°:
        num13 = num13 + 1
        sum1  = sum1 + a
        sum3  = sum3 + a + 180°
    else if a > 135°:
        num13 = num13 + 1
        sum1  = sum1 + a - 180°
        sum3  = sum3 + a
    else:
       num2 = num2 + 1
       sum2 = sum2 + a
    end if

end for

avg1 = (sum1 + sum2) / (num13 + num2)
avg2 = (sum2 + sum3) / (num13 + num2)

if abs(avg1 - 90°) <= abs(avg2 - 90°):
    return avg1
else:
    return avg2
```

Note that the result will be within 0° and 180°, inclusive.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much!